# Printing Html Document formatted with CSS

Tags: css, html, printing

I have a asp.net mvc application and my Views are in HTML5. I need to print a view as a report. This View shows some data with `<table/>` tag and it is formatted with css style as `font-family`, `font-size`, `text-align` properties etc. When I try to print it with Chrome (exporting to PDF) my css does not work, I mean, the print's result is shown without formating.

What can I do to solve this problem? It Does not matter whether I use css to apply the style or use html tags to format the page, but I wish it would leave the impression formatted.

PS: I would like to keep the html valid document.

Comment: Can you try adding -webkit-print-color-adjust to the body element in your print stylesheet.

Comment: This article may be helpful, Designing for Print with CSS (Jan, 2015) https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/ as it talks about using CSS for publications as well as web sites that are printed. I am running into the same issue with printing HTML pages with tables and I am wondering if div should be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different styles for screen and print media in your style sheet, i.e.

```
@media screen
{
    table.test {
        font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia;
        font-size:10px;
        // more
    }
}

@media print
{
    table.test {
        font-family:Verdana, Arial;
        font-size:10px;
        // more
    }
}
```

When you'll print the table only styles defined in print media will be applied.

[**Check this for more**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).

Comment: Is it work on the <style> tg inside the page or I have to do it on a separate file and include with `<link />` tag?

Comment: You can use same `style.css` file, just use `@media print` to declare the styles for `print` and also you can keep it in a separate `css` file or `<style>` tag inside the page but styles should be define within `@media print{// your style goes here}`.

Comment: Thank you man. Some properties does not work like background-color :(.. but I help me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to split up the css for screen and print separately just by following setting

```
<link href="css/main.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

then no need to change your html code just change the css or duplicate the old css.

Comment: This is awesome (10 yrs later!). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define the css semantics with `@media print` rule, then stylize the stylesheet with that in mind. Maybe this help.